Can the proximal operator $\mathrm{prox}_{\lambda f}(x)$, as a function of $\lambda$, be discontinuous?
Given a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to (-\infty,+\infty]$ proper, convex and lower semicontinuos, I am wondering about two (quite related) things.

Is the curve $\lambda \mapsto \mathrm{prox}_{\lambda f}(x^0) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ always continuous?
Is the function $\lambda \mapsto f(\mathrm{prox}_{\lambda f}(x^0)) \in \mathbb{R} $ always continuous?

Some remarks:

$1.\Rightarrow 2.\,$, because $f$ is continuous on its domain, being convex.
The function $\lambda \mapsto f(\mathrm{prox}_{\lambda f}(x^0)) $ is always nonincreasing (see Bauschke & Combettes (2nd Ed.), Prop. 12.27), and a monotone function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, except at a zero-measure set of jump discontinuities. So, in a sense, I would just need to get rid of the jump discontinuities (or find one as a counterexample).
I tried to consider some properties of the Moreau envelope $f^{(\lambda)}(x^0):=\mathrm{min}_x f(x) + \tfrac{1}{2\lambda}\|x-x^0\|^2$. For example:
$$ f^{(\lambda)}(x) = f(\mathrm{prox}_{\lambda f}(x)) + \tfrac{1}{2\lambda}\|\mathrm{prox}_{\lambda f}(x) -x\|^2 $$
but I didn't find anything useful.


I found a reference which claims that 1. is proven in (3.76) in Attouch, H.: Variational convergence for functions and operators, vol. 1., (1984). I do not have this book, so I am unable to verify.

Thanks a lot! I'll look into it.

Take $0<\lambda _1<\lambda_2$ and set $x_i :=prox_{\lambda_i f}(x_0)$. Then we have the following inclusions for the subdifferentials
$$
-\lambda_i^{-1} (x_i-x_0) \in \partial f(x_i)  \quad i=1,2.
$$
Then
$$
\langle -\lambda_1^{-1} (x_1-x_0) +\lambda_2^{-1} (x_2-x_0), x_1 - x_2 \rangle \ge0,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\lambda_2^{-1} \|x_1-x_2\|^2 \le (\lambda_2^{-1} -\lambda_1^{-1}) \langle x_1-x_0, x_1-x_2\rangle.
$$
This implies
$$
\lambda_2^{-1} \|x_1-x_2\| \le |\lambda_2^{-1} -\lambda_1^{-1}| \cdot \|x_1-x_0\|
$$
or
$$
\lambda_1 \|x_1-x_2\| \le |\lambda_1 -\lambda_2| \cdot \|x_1-x_0\|.
$$
From here, it should be easy to argue continuity of $\lambda \mapsto x$.

Thanks! Your proof is clear and looks basically complete to me: one just needs to take the right and left limits as $\lambda_2 \to \lambda_1^+,\ \lambda_1 \to \lambda_2^-$ and show that $|x_2-x_1|\to0$, right?

For the limit $\lambda_1 \to \lambda_2$, one needs one more triangle inequality $|x_1-x_0| \le |x_2-x_0| + |x_1-x_2|$.

It looks to me that this also shows that $\lambda\mapsto \mathrm{prox}{\lambda f}(x^0)$ is locally Lipschitz, so a.e. differentiable! That'd be because $\frac{|\mathrm{prox}{\lambda_1 f}(x^0)-x_0|}{\lambda_1}$ is locally bounded on $(0,+\infty)$.
